# What type of bumper/pad to use with glass table top protector on top of veneer surface?

Tags: furniture, glass

My nightstand has a veneer surface that seems to discolor when in contact with any significant moisture. To mitigate this and have the nightstand be more functional, I've decided to put a glass sheet on top and need to purchase bumpers/pads to keep the glass from sliding off. I've heard that some material, like rubber and silicone, can tend to stick to surfaces and I'm worried about getting any bumpers/pads that could damage the veneer surface. What are safe materials to use as a bumper/pad for glass that won't affect veneer? Is there a different approach I could use to keep the glass from sliding off the nightstand?

Comment: What kind of "veneer" and how is it finished? Is it a plastic-like laminate (like a kitchen cabinet), or is it a real wood veneer (what sort of finish), or something else?

Comment: I used four dots of hotglue to create a standoff between a table top and a glass top. They should be easily removable with a hair dryer, but if in doubt, you can squirt out four pads on the glass, let them cool, then flip over and put on the table. They also sell ultra-clear discs for just this purpose, but I couldn't find them for sale anywhere; i think they might only come with new furnature.

Comment: Glass slides pretty easily even with silicone and its also flexible. You might want to considerit flush mounted with tiny bead of clear sealant on the end, which peals off easily but may have better grip.

Comment: @FreeMan The item description only mentions "FSC-certified solid mahogany veneer"